# is Matlab computer vision camera-1 the right-hand camera from perspective of behind or in front?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, matlab-cvst, stereo-3d

Matlab's programming guide states that stereo camera-1 is the right-hand camera, and cam-2 is left-hand.

But it does not define if right-hand means in front of the stereo cameras (perspective of looking AT the lenses) or behind the camera (facing the non-lenses back side of the cameras).

Comment: And what do you see if you display the images from e.g. camera-1? That should tell you....

Comment: Meh, left shmeft: just look at the world-to-camera matrices returned by the calibration, and see which way the translation vectors are pointing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which programming guide?  When you calibrate a stereo pair, either camera can be camera 1. It is easier if camera 1 is the left camera, because otherwise your disparity will be negative. And left means camera's left, i.e. left as you look in the same direction as the cameras.